# Pull data from footer into the body (or into a new report)

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I have an SSRS report. At the level of the footer I'm showing the table index of a table added in the report body, because it contains more than 500 pages (the table index is drawn from code "concatenating the report group name with the page number").

I need to pull this data from the footer to the body; I can't insert this data directly in the report body part, because it contains a page number, which is forbidden in the body. So: is it possible to read this data and insert it in a new report, or is there any other solution that would help?

Answer (score 0):

The report body is not aware what pages will be generated when the report is rendered. You cannot achieve what you want in the report body.